# Output Directory Contents to File

Tags: command-line, filesystem, files, directory, ls

I have a directory **html**. I would like to output the files of the directory, including the path, to a file.

You can do something like this with the command:

```
ls -R scripts/html > out.txt
```

But the results are like:

```
scripts/html
1.html
2.html
...
```

I would like the result as:

```
scripts/html/1.html
scripts/html/2.html
...
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1767384/ls-command-how-can-i-get-a-recursive-full-path-listing-one-line-per-file - Several good solutions on that question / answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `find` instead of `ls`. It'll give you a relative path based on what you pass it. I'm using `tail` to snip off the first line which would normally show the base directory.

```
find scripts/html | tail -n+2 > out.txt
```

Comment: Thank you. That is perfect. But is there any way to exclude the directory from the first line? I'll try something, but am a novice. I believe sed could be used.

Comment: @KohjahBreese I've edited to do that. And it turns out you don't need `stdbuf` for find (I wonder what I was thinking of).

Comment: A simpler solution is simply: find dir/* > file.txt

Comment: @KohjahBreese The only problem I can see from that is won't (it might) list hidden directories in the first layer (but it will in subsequent).

Answer (score 2):

in the directory you want to show the contents of:

for all (folders and files)

```
ls -d1 $PWD/**/*
```

for just folders

```
ls -d1 $PWD/**
```

for just files

```
ls -d1 $PWD/*.*
```

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use this to print files only:

```bash
find scripts/html '!' -type d
```

Anything that is not a directory will be printed.